# Возвращает undefined и не может прочитать стиль

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый День! Столкнулся с проблемой, **JS** никак не может понять стиль и выдает ошибку в `console.log` каждый раз.
Кто знает, в чем может заключаться проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
  function closeDialog(fromMask) {
        if (fromMask === undefined){
            fromMask = false;
        }
        console.log("TEST mask", fromMask);
        if (canncellable === true) {
            $("#mask").fadeOut(300);
            $(popup_id).fadeOut(300);
            document.getElementById(popup_id).style.display = "none"
        } else if(fromMask === false){
            canncellable = true;
            closeDialog(false);
        }
        resetIconToHidden()
    }

    function resetIconToHidden() {

        let popupContainer = document.getElementById(popup_id);
        popupContainer.getElementsByClassName("icon")[0].style.display = "none";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById(popup_id)` возвращает `undefined`. Это значит, что нет в документе элемента у которого `id` совпадает со значением, которое хранится в переменной `popup_id`.

Для начала выведите в лог значение `popup_id` и убедитесь, что там находится то, что Вы ожидаете

Судя по строке

```
 $(popup_id).fadeOut(300);
```

в `popup_id` находится значение, начинающееся с символа `#`, который в jQuery обозначает, что в строке содержится id элемента, а для метода `getElementById` этот символ не нужен, и браузер считает, что Вы ищете элемент с id `#xxx`

А вообще, раз Вы уже нашли этот элемент при помощи jQuery, так и продолжайте работать с ним

```
 $(popup_id).fadeOut(300).css({display: none});
```

Но смысла ставить `display: none` нет никакого. Т.к. `jQuery.fadeOut(..)` сам это сделает по окончанию своей работы

Comment: спасибо за ответ, попробую исправить проблему)

Comment: @OlegSevernuy Я обновил ответ. Перечитайте его